# azure data factory copy activity pick only first 100 files

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to copy files from one blob account to another blob using Azure Data Factory . However my source blob has 25k + files (XML). I just want to copy 100 files for my initial testing.

How to achieve it ?

Comment: The first 100 files? Or the latest 100 files?

Comment: Anything ... I am just looking to test.

Comment: it can be achieved with many actives，and may be complex and not directly . Is that ok?

Comment: Currently , I am using wildcard so that I dont pick all the files. If something is similar to that it will be helpful.

Comment: Another questions, do the files have same naming rule or named  random?

Comment: You can ref the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520585/azure-data-factory-set-a-limit-to-copy-number-of-files-using-copy-activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use AzCopy to specify selected files to COPY or if you just want to test your pipeline then create another container, place only few files and then point your ADF to new container to test your pipeline.

More information can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/wiki/Listing-specific-files-to-transfer) if you need to use AzCopy

Comment: Hi @Amit : If my response helped you, can you please mark it as an answer so that we can have others from community to benefit from it :). Thanks !